# Authorization with Javascript SDK api calls

Tags: authorization, facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token

I'm using the javascript sdk and I'm unclear about when I can make api calls. FB.api works just fine within the FB.getLoginStatus function, but the FB.api call on its own below prints the name 'undefined'. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental. Should I be using the access token in some way?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

              // SUCCESS
              alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
        });
     }

});

FB.api('/me', function(response) {

     //FAILURE
     alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be sure the framework is loaded before calling or attaching FB.* to any javascript handlers.

You can ensure you get it done at the right time by putting the attachment to handlers inside of the `window.fbAsyncInit=function(){};`

Also, your first example is correct, you want to ensure the user is connected/logged in prior to just blindly calling `FB.api(` or `FB.ui(` functions.

Comment: Oh yes I loaded the framework asynchronously, I just didn't show it in this example. But thanks for confirming that FB.api can only be called after ensuring that the user is connected.